# MediaPlayer.create() returns NULL

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I followed a youtube tutorial that showed how to create an android mp3 player app. The App has multiple buttons, one for previous song, one for Pause/Play and one for next song. Play/Pause buttons, only pause my MediaPlayer and they work perfectly no matter how many times i click them.

On the other hand, Next/Previous buttons causes my code to throw NullPointerException. I found out it was because `MediaPlayer.create(Context, Uri)` function sometimes returns null. On my app, function fails approx. on every tenth press of Next button, or on every tenth creation of MediaPlayer.

Is there a way to fix this? I tried modifying application on my own, but it didn't work. I tried looping variable `myMysicPlayer` in continue while loop, until it gets `while != null`

```
while(myMusicPlayer != null){
 Uri u = new Uri(...);
 myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getAppContext(), u);
}
```

I tried using a listener that waits till `myMusicPlayer` was ready to be stopped, but it was just dereferencing null, and that failed obviosely.

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
myMediaPlayer.stop();
myMediaPlayer.reset();
myMediaPlayer.release();
position = (position + 1) % mySongs.size();
Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());                    
songLabelName.setText(mySongs.get(position).toString());    
myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
myMediaPlayer.start();    
}
});
```

The error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aizenangel.myapplication, PID: 20169
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference            at com.aizenangel.myapplication.SongPlayer$4.onClick(SongPlayer.java:168)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20169 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should not ever be creating more than 1 MediaPlayer per Activity. These are large, expensive objects. Creating a lot of them causes problems. These should instead be shared between multiple uses of media player.

Comment: Can i play more than one song on the same MediaPlayer? I mean can i create MediaPlayer instance only once and than just switch between songs, without releasing MediaPlayer object (like i've done so far)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was: 
1) i used `myMediaPlayer.release()` method, that releases all resources 
   associated with the `MediaPlayer` object 
2) instead of using the same `MediaPlayer` object, i always create new one with  `myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Context, Uri),` and 
`MediaPlayer.create(Context, Uri)` returns null on failure, which than causes `NullPointerException`.

Solution was simple. I deleted `myMediaPlayer.release()` line and instead of creating new object, i modified the one whose reference i got in the begining.

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
   myMediaPlayer.stop();
   myMediaPlayer.reset();
   position = (position+1)%mySongs.size();
   Uri u = Uri.parse((mySongs.get(position)).toString());
   songLabelName.setText(mySongs.get(position).toString());
   try {
    myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
    myMediaPlayer.prepare();
   }catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
     myMediaPlayer.start();
    }
   });
  }
});
```